# Assign Values from Array to Array

Tags: replacement, symbolic, list-manipulation

I am trying to simply do the following

`cVec = {a,b,c,d}`

From another expression, I obtain another vector, say,

`uVec = {k,l,m,n}`

What I try to do is to assign each value to other value, like:

```
a = k
b = l
c = m
d = n
```

As you may imagine, I do not have four values but several values, so writing each assignment would be cumbersome. I am trying to find easy way to assign the values.

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Will you do this assignment more than once? Why not consider using an Association instead? Note that both of the answers below will only work once.

Comment: I will do this only once, yes. So far, the given answers are sufficient to solve my problem. Since I am quite new to Mathematica, I do not know how Association works. I will check it also. Thank you.

Comment: @nicomedian Welcome to Mathematica.SE.  I have marked your question as a duplicate; please see the links inserted above your post for existing Q&A's on this topic.  This does *not* mean your question is bad, it is a matter of site organization.

Answer (score 3):

```
cVec = {a, b, c, d};
uVec = {k, l, m, n};

With[{z = cVec}, z = uVec];

a
```

> k

also

```
Clear[a, b, c, d]

x = cVec;

With[{z = x}, z = uVec];
```

Comment: That worked great, thank you. Is there a way not to write explicity cVec in With[] command but define it above?

Comment: Yes, now updated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[cVec, uVec, a, b, c, d, k, l, m, n];
cVec = {a, b, c, d};
uVec = {k, l, m, n};
Set @@@ Thread[{cVec, uVec}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) wrapping `cVec` with [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html):

```
Evaluate[cVec] = uVec;
cVec
```

> {k, l, m, n}

```
c
```

> m

You can also use [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html):

```
ClearAll[cVec, a, b, c, d]
cVec = {a, b, c, d};

MapThread[Set, {cVec, uVec}];

cVec
```

> {k, l, m, n}

Comment: That also worked great, thank you.